# Store value of last runtime without session

Tags: php, instance

I met storage problem with php.
What I want is when ***each time*** I visit the **function Main** of Class A, I can get the **value of variable $temp of last time.**
P.s. I know I can use session, but it wastes many memory, and not safe.

**so I want to find another solution.**
Below is the code.

```
class A {
     //initilize the value, how to make it just initialize once?
     private static $temp = 0;

     public function Main() {
         echo "Last time I was=". $this->temp;
         $this->temp += 1;
     }    
}
```

Thank you for your guys' help! Waiting for your idea

Comment: Why don't you store it in a database?

Comment: Why don't you store it in a cookie? How big do you expect your sessions to be to take up so much memory and why aren't they secure?

Comment: Why don't you think sessions are safe?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I think the data is not too big, not need to store it in a database.

Comment: @Script47 Yes, I get it, thank you~

Comment: @Barmar Because I think it is easily got by programmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static variable value is stored in a request lifetime.sessions are safe enough to even store authentication data in it so if you want to store this data between multiple requests i recommend sessions or database.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, it is in a request lifetime!

Answer (score 0):

Will it be useful if you store it in a separate file,  you overwrite the value in it and read from it when needed?

Comment: will it be a little slow to open/close the stream of file

Comment: No, it would not be time-consuming, unless you use the variable thousands of times in a single second (I don't know exactly for what purpose this variable is used). But you can also use the session to store the variable - this should not cause problems, I believe.